# Calculating effective capacitance of a circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance

Please refer to the image below.
The question asks: 'The effective capacitance between terminals A and B in the network shown in the adjoining figure is?'

Here is my working:
(C5 and C6 connected in series.. in parallel to C2 and C4 connected in series).. connected in series with C1 and C3.
Series(C5+C6) = 1 microFarad
Series(C2+C4) = 1.5 microFarads
Parallel (1+1.5) = 2.5 microFarads
Series(C1+C3+2.5) = **15/26 microFarads** (Answer)

The correct answer from the marking scheme is 8/3 microFarads. Could someone please explain how to get to this answer? I am really confused.

Thanks

[image: The effective capacitance between terminals A and B in the network shown in the adjoining figure is?]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: I'm a university student. My finals are coming up this month. I can assure you that this is just a revision question, and not a homework one

Comment: You should read the links he posted.  It doesn't matter if its actually a homework question.  The question is "homework-like".  The links will answer the question of what is considered to be on-topic when it comes to these types of questions.

Comment: I do not like this educators-learners attitude. I am pretty sure there are many students, like me, who find solving questions the best way to learn. Anyway, rules are rules!

Comment: You'd be surprised how many people come here and ask us to do their homework for them and make no effort to learn.  I'm not saying thats what you have done here, but that is the reason the rules are the way they are.

Comment: The problem with just giving the answer is the asker doesn't learn, and neither does anyone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to understand the issue is that between the upper and lower "corner" of the circuit the voltage is always zero, therefore no current will flow across $\mathrm C_5$ and $\mathrm C_6$.

In "corners" I mean the points common to $\mathrm C_3$-$\mathrm C_4$ and $\mathrm C_1$-$\mathrm C_2$. These pairs of capacitors are effectively voltage dividers. Whatever the voltage is between $A$ and $B$, these dividers divide it by the same 2:1 ratio, yielding the same voltage.

Because of this you can entirely omit $\mathrm C_5$ and $\mathrm C_6$.

What's left is $\mathrm C_1-\mathrm C_2$ series $=2\;\mathrm{\mu F}$ paralleled with $\mathrm C_3-\mathrm C_4$ in series $= 2/3 \:\mathrm{\mu F}$, so  $6/3 + 2/3 = 8/3 \:\mathrm{\mu F}$.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to me. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: " between the upper and lower "corner" of the circuit the voltage is always zero,"  I'm interested in a proof of that, that is, why do C5 and C6, not affect the voltage divider, (if you will edit your answer; don't give the proof in these comments).

Comment: The second paragraph briefly explains it. The "hard way" (and the precise way) would be to write and solve the equations for the voltages across / currents through each device using Kirchhoff's laws.

Comment: @BillN Another way I thought of this is: since C1/C2 = C3/C4, both the upper and lower 'corners' are at the same potential. So potential difference between these two 'corners' = 0

Comment: So it's *only* true for a balanced bridge, not for a bridge circuit in general.

Comment: That's right Bill!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Using Kirchhoff's First Rule**,finding charges in capacitors between D & C (Let it be $Q_m$). 
$$
Q_1-Q_m-Q_2=0\\
Q_3+Q_m-Q_4=0\\
$$
**Using Kirchhoff's Second Rule**,finding voltages loops ***ADC & DBC***.
$$
\frac{Q_1}{C_1}+\frac{Q_m}{C_m}-\frac{Q_3}{C_3}=0\\
\frac{Q_2}{C_2}-\frac{Q_4}{C_4}-\frac{Q_m}{C_m}=0
$$
When the Bridge is balanced,$Q_m=0$,So the set of equations can be rewritten as,
$$
Q_1=Q_2\\
Q_3=Q_4\\
Q_1.C_3=Q_3.C_1\space--(1)\\
Q_2.C_4=Q_4.C_2\space--(2)
$$
Dividing **1 & 2**,We get,
$$
\frac{C_3}{C_4}=\frac{C_1}{C_2}
$$
From this we can see that the bridge is balanced. Since $\frac{3}{6}=\frac{1}{2}$
Therefore Capacitors $C_5$ & $C_6$ can be taken off.